# Send 1000 requests per second to the azure event hub using azure event hub sampler in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, azure-eventhub, jmeter-plugins, azure-load-testing

I need to send 1000 telemetry messages to the event hub using Jmeter GUI.
I am using Azure Event Hubs Sampler to connect to the event hub and Throughput Shaping Timer to provide required start,end RPS and duration of the test

But failing to achieve the same
I am attaching my test plan here:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEVnt.png)

Test plan to send data to event hubs usinh JMeter

Answer (score 0):

In your current setup Throughput Shaping Timer can only **pause** JMeter threads in order to **limit** the load to the desired value.

With 10 threads you can only reach 1000 requests per second if 1 user executes 100 requests per second and it can only be done if response time is 10 milliseconds or less.

The options are in:

1. Take a look at your response time and increase the number of threads in the Thread Group proportionally, this way you will be able to get more throughput (hopefully)
2. Consider switching to [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/), it can be connected with the Throughput Shaping Timer via [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function), this way JMeter will be able to kick off more threads if the current amount is not enough for conducting the required load.

More information: [Using JMeter’s Throughput Shaping Timer Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin)

Comment: Hello Dmitri, Thank you for your response.I have tried the Concurrency thread group but it is also not working either I am attaching my results please have a look  and suggest possible enhancements  
[![Image Description](https://i.ibb.co/5hKD8k8/image.png)](https://ibb.co/5hKD8k8)
[![Image Description](https://i.ibb.co/HhHVhpf/image.png)](https://ibb.co/HhHVhpf)
[![Image Description](https://i.ibb.co/vw0C5mg/image.png)](https://ibb.co/vw0C5mg)
[![Image Description](https://i.ibb.co/YTk5NYS/image.png)](https://ibb.co/YTk5NYS)